# How to make a specific vertical electric/electric displacement field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, charge

I wanted to try to make a sphere (with net charge $q$) float with electrical force so I applied the fact for the ball to be at rest the net forces to be 0. I assumed the only other force than gravity would be the Lorentz force. And if the ball is staying still in the air then the velocity field is the 0 vector. Then $F=q\overrightarrow E$. Solving out (I know $\overrightarrow g$ is not just a constant vector because of Gauss' law for gravity but I assumed it wouldn't make much difference) I got $\overrightarrow E= \frac{9.8m}{q}\hat{j}$. Since (if I can make it) The charges would be in air so I used the constituent relation $\epsilon\overrightarrow E=D$ (no free charges) then the relation would become $\overrightarrow D= \frac{9.8\epsilon m}{q}\hat{j}$. Is there a way to actually create this field (outside the region of the sphere the electric/electric displacement field should be 0)? If so, what components would I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get two metal plates that are quite a bit wider than the sphere in question. Place them parallel to the ground, one above the other, forming a parallel plate capacitor. They should be electrically insulated from the environment and as closely spaced as you can have them with the sphere in between. Connect a DC voltage supply across the two plates. This will create an electric field between the two plates. If $V$ is the supply voltage and $d$ is the separation of the plates, the maximum electric field between the plates will be $V/d$, probably somewhat less depending on how far apart the plates are.

The voltage supply can actually be a [full-wave rectified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier#Full-wave_rectification) AC voltage source, in which case $V$ is the average voltage across the plates (about $2/\pi$ times the peak voltage). You might find that you will either need a very light or highly charged ball, a very high voltage, or very close plates to accomplish what you want. To avoid the risk of electrocution, I strongly suggest you don't attempt this experiment with voltages exceeding ~30 V, unless you know what you are doing.